# How can I use a variable in a T-SQL partition function?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I'm confused about the definition for boundary_values in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as related to constants and expressions.

I have created partitioned tables in MSSQL, so I know how to set the values for the "partition functions".  I also have a stored procedure that updates the boundary values for two partition functions every month, so I know how to programmatically create the functions.

But I recently re-read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION.  The syntax is:

```sql
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name ( input_parameter_type )  
AS RANGE [ LEFT | RIGHT ]   
FOR VALUES ( [ *boundary_value* [ ,...n ] ] )
```

The explanation has these sentences that baffle me:

> boundary_value is a constant expression that can reference variables. This includes user-defined type variables, or functions and user-defined functions. It cannot reference Transact-SQL expressions.

How can a constant expression "reference" a variable?  According to the doc on [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql), a constant expression is "a symbol that represents a single, specific data value. For more information, see [Constants (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).".  That link says that a character constant, for example, is just some stuff between quote marks. Numeric constants are just a single number. This says that variables can't be used in a constant expression -- that would be a Transact-SQL expression.

And the "functions and user-defined functions" phrase also baffles me.

There are lots of examples of how to programmatically build boundary values, especially when working with dates, but they just programmatically make one large SQL expression using Create Partition Function and appending the boundary values (usually in a loop).  That's not setting the *boundary_value* to a constant expression that's "referencing" a "variable".  And it's not using functions. I have seen no examples that would illuminate how to reference a variable, or use a function, in the *boundary_value*.

Does anyone understand what this is trying to say?

Comment: This, in truth, sounds like something you should be raising on the documentation's GitHub.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu that "constant expression that can reference variables" is a doc issue. You can raise a pull request for that. You didn't ask this question but you can reference a variable in `ALTER...SPLIT`, commonly used for partition maintenance: `DECLARE @NewBoundary date = '2022010-13';ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Date() SPLIT RANGE(@NewBoundary);`. A `NEXT USED` filegroup needs to be set on schemes that reference the function before doing so.

Comment: "functions and user-defined functions" probably refers to both system functions and UDFs. The phraseology of variables and constants is probably wrong as you say. Either way, this question should probably be migrated to [dba.se]

Comment: Dan, in an earlier version of SQL Server (2000, I think), the expression that used a variable in the Split function always gave an error, in spite of the doc.  I had to build and execute an expression to make a split happen using a variable.   And I was thinking about Create Partition Function, not the split thing.  And Charlie, you are probably right, but still, in Create Partition Function, you need to give constants (which is just dumb, because SQL is a data-driven thing.

Comment: I want to start a movement for "expressions everywhere" -- all of the places that don't take expressions, like the parameters to stored procedures, ought to take expressions.